# How to fix the window title for an application (Android Studio)?

Tags: .desktop, window, wayland, android-studio, titlebar

I am running the latest **Android Studio** version on Ubuntu 22.04.1 (Wayland). The corresponding `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications` looks like this:

```properties
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Android Studio Flamingo 2022.2.x
Icon=/home/jjd/bin/android-studio-2022.1.x-linux/bin/studio.png
Exec=bash "/home/jjd/bin/android-studio-2022.1.x-linux/bin/studio.sh" %f
Comment=Develop with pleasure!
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-android-studio
```

For some reason the **top window title** shows a **different name**: `Android Studio 4.2.2`. That is the `Name` of an much older version of the application. How comes this is shown instead of `Android Studio Flamingo 2022.2.x` which is defined in the `.desktop` file?

[image]

Comment: You may have a different `.desktop` file lurking about somewhere. Have you searched your machine for all `.desktop` files?

Comment: There is other `.desktop` files in `~/.local/share/applications` for each major version of Android Studio which I want to keep. One of them contains the `Name=Android Studio 4.2.2` but this points to the respective executable **not** to the one outlined in my question. Is there another location where `.desktop` files are usually stored?

Comment: `/usr/share/applications/` is the system-side folder for associating `.desktop` files to applications. Since it sounds like you're running different versions of the same application, my guess is that there is some issue with the proper `.desktop` file getting associated with the two (or more?) applications in question. To test this, you may want to edit the `Name` string to see if the text "Android Studio 4.2.2" changes. If so, you've confirmed the active `.desktop` file.

Comment: I can confirm it is the file. I also found a difference in the file. The `Exec` is set to `Exec="/home/jjd/...` instead of `Exec=bash "/home/jjd/` like in the example above. Prefixing `bash ` did not help, though. Also `StartupWMClass=jetbrains-studio` vs. `StartupWMClass=jetbrains-android-studio`. When I delete the file then the window title changes to `jetbrains-studio`. Strange behavior altogether.